# Excel: Calculate earned income based on multiple variables depending on period of day worked

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need help putting my excel worksheet to use. The case is if I work between 18:00 - 22:00 I have a income multiplier of 1.2. If i work from 22:00 - 06:00 I have a multiplier of 1.4. 06:00 - 08:00 is 1.2 again.

Now sometimes I work from 19:00 - 23:00. So I can't simply say 4 * (income * 1.2) because the last hour is * 1.4. How can I go about this? Currently I have this calculation:

[image]

Which does the job partly, it miscalculates the 22-23 hours and the 06-06:30 hours. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you either start at 1:00 or 19:00 so, if that's always true, two fairly simple formulas will suffice.  In the chart below, I've calculated the "Equivalent" hours worked, figuring in the multipliers.  These numbers can be multiplied by your hourly base pay rate to get the $ (or fl?) amount earned.

[image]

The formula in column C where the start time is 19:00 is:

```
=24*(IF(B2-TIME(22,0,0)>0,(TIME(22,0,0)-A2)*1.2+(B2-TIME(22,0,0))*1.4,(B2-A2)*1.2))
```

and where the start time is 1:00:

```
=24*(IF(B6-TIME(6,0,0)>0,(TIME(6,0,0)-A6)*1.4+(B6-TIME(6,0,0))*1.2,(B6-A6)*1.4))
```

Multiplying by 24 converts the time into decimal hours, and the TIME(hh,mm,ss) function allows calculations using the "constant" times - 22:00 or 6:00.

If you want to have only one formula, you can combine these two equations using a (somewhat convoluted) IF() that checks for the start time.  If the start times can be other than 19:00 or 1:00, that would make things a bit more complicated.

Let me know how this works for you.  Good luck.